# How to send the Model to a partial view and change it's value in the controller before it arrives to the partial view and update with ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Hi what I want is to call a partial view from 'index.cshtml' passing it the model and some string input and when we get to the function 'ContactsTable'  in the controller i want to get the model which of type List
and to filter it's values 
and then send the new list to the partial view

After completeing this I want to use ajax to recall the partial view

I need help with accessing the model from the controller and the ajax function

Thank you

Comment: Uncomment `public string Search { get; set; }`. Delete that awful manual input and replace it with `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Search )` and and then delete all your scripts and replace with `$('#Search ').change(function() { $('#ContactsTable]).load(@Url.Action(""), { search: $(this).val() }); });` and the method is `public ActionResult ContactsTable(string search) {`

Comment: But then How can I accsess the model (I mean the List<Contacts>) from this function:public ActionResult ContactsTable(string search) ?

Comment: Your don't (you not passing a `List<Contacts>` to that method and it would be crazy to event try). Inside the method you use `IQueryable<Contact> contactsList = db.Contacts;` to call your database (and note you use `IQueryable<T>`, not `List<T>`).

Comment: And you should have a button to perform the search (as per the dupe), not handle the `.change()` event of the textbox.

Comment: But all the point here is not to have a button and show the result while typing, and go to db every type will be crazy

Comment: maybe there is a way to filter the list in the index file as i'm doing in public ActionResult ContactsTable func and then send the filtered data to the partial view but also maintain the orginial list until the page refresh

Comment: What is crazy is to attempt to pass back the whole collection back to a server method (which means you would need to generate hidden inputs with indexers for every property of every object in the collection. And if your initially displaying all objects, then you can just use javascript to filter it in the browser.

Comment: And do not change your original question and invalidate comments./answers. If you want to show additional code, then append it to your original question (I have rolled back your changes)

Comment: but is it possible to do my other suggestion?

Comment: Your saying that _go to db every type will be crazy_? That is not nearly as crazy as  posting back the whole collection across the wire each time you press a key. If your initial view displays all `Contact` objects, then just use javascript/jquery to filter the html in the view (by showing/hiding rows that match the text in the textbox)

Comment: This is my first project in asp.net mvs so I didn't know,
instead of hiding rows it doesn't better to rebuild the table?

Comment: [This article](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp) should give your a general idea of how to filter your table based on the search text (no unnecessary ajax calls back to the server)

Comment: Thank you very much